# PHP Error is Saying CONSTANT is not Defined but its already defined and Value is Empty?

Tags: php, constants

I have following setup (Architecture) on my Web Design Project. Which is not working on a due to some reason.

I have the index.php page with following includes on the top

```
require_once("includes/init.php");
```

Then in my init.php i have

```
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');
ob_start();
spl_autoload_register('load_api');
$db      = new Database();
$db->connect();
```

And in my Config file i have following defined

```
 define('DOC_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/websitename");
define('CLASS_LIB', DOC_ROOT . "/classes");
```

And in my Auto Loading Functions include contains

```
function load_api($class){
    if(!file_exists(CLASS_LIB."/".$class. '.class.php') )
        return false;
    require_once( CLASS_LIB."/".$class. '.class.php');
    return true;
}
```

When i run this design structure in my xamp/xdebugger it errors out

```
( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant CLASS_LIB - assumed 'CLASS_LIB' in D:\websitename\includes\functions.php on line 7
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  144128  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0020  155632  require_once( 'D:\websitenae\includes\init.php' )   ..\index.php:2
3   0.0129  400360  spl_autoload_call ( 'Database' )    ..\index.php:6
4   0.0129  400408  load_api( $class = 'Database' ) ..\index.php:0

( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in D:\websitename\includes\init.php on line 6
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  144128  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0020  155632  require_once( 'D:\websitename\includes\init.php' )  ..\index.php:2
```

Error seems to be that CLASS_LIB is not detected, however i cant figure out why because it seems to already defined correctly and loading before this script, plus i dont see double inclusion also in the code...any ideas is appreciated much ?

Comment: Put a debugger statement in your config file, after the constant definition, and make sure that it stops there and that the value of the constant is correct. There's a chance it simply never reaches that point for whatever reason.

Comment: No change as you can clearly see.  Configuration is required once and called before the execution.

Comment: yes, didnt work, however debugging shows although config file was included(required doesn't give any errors) but none of the content in the config including defined values aren't actually been executed..even simple echo in the config dont get executed but dont give me a error in the require() too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it, this could happen to anyone and therefore i am posting this as the solution.

When i run this i didn't got any errors from the require() function, because its loading the a config file, however i found that its not loading the correct config file in the given location,

instead its going to the PEAR include location and loading exact name file called "config.php", that's why require didn't gave me the error and that's why my config file vars was not loaded.

So to fix i have to specify the explicit path for the my config like below

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/config.php');
```

That solved the problem :) very tricky

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know **ob_start();** must be on top and **ob_end_flush();** on bottom.

```
ob_start(); // top
//
//
ob_end_flush(); // bottom
```

Comment: nothing to do with the ob_start() doewsnt work even without them

Comment: ob_start();
require_once("includes/init.php");
require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');

try this or check your connect data

Comment: Doesn't work even without the ob. Nothing is changed even if I put it in the top.

Comment: u added to ob_end_flush(); on bottom _?

Comment: yes, didnt work, however debugging shows although config file was included(required doesn't give any errors) but none of the content in the config including defined values aren't actually been executed..even simple echo in the config dont get executed but dont give me a error in the require() too...